# URL encoding not working in Yii2 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, yii2

I am working on Yii2 framework and using jQuery `$.post()` method to fetch data from URL.
The URL send from jQuery is as follows:

```
http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=visitor%2Fcenter%26location_id%3D6
```

which is giving `404 Page Not found Error`.

At the same time, when I use the following URL from the browser using & and =,

```
http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=visitor%2Fcenter&location_id=6
```

I am able to get the results as follows:

```
c_center4
c_center3
c_center2
c_center1
```

My jQuery code within view looks like this.

```
[
         'onchange' => '
                console.log("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('visitor/center&location_id=').'" +$(this).val());
                $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('visitor/center&location_id=').'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                  $( "select#visitor_center" ).html( data );
                });
        ']
```

I am not able to figure out the reason.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass query string in this way. If you pass string to `createUrl()` it will be treated as route and all special characters will be encoded (since `visitor/center&location_id=` should be treated as value of `r` param, so it needs to be encoded).

You may try something like this:

```
[
    'onchange' => '
        $url = "' . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['visitor/center', 'location_id' => '']) . '" + $(this).val(); 
        console.log($url);',
]
```

This should generate route and param separately without unneeded encoding.

Comment: I tried that. But the code `'onchange' => '$url = Yii::$app->urlManager->createURL(['visitor/center', 'location_id' => '100']);
                        console.log($url);'` is giving `syntax error, unexpected 'visitor' (T_STRING), expecting ']'`

Comment: Your quotes are incorrect, try `'onchange' => '$url = "' . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['visitor/center', 'location_id' => '100']) . '"; console.log($url);'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking about this. But bit confused with quotes.

Comment: Could please help me that I don't want 100 to be hardcoded, it will be the input to the function, so I need `$(this).val()` instead of 100. I am trying but of no use. Quoates are confusing me.

Comment: In my example in answer there is no hardcoded value, there is empty string as param value, so you should be able to append ID in JS at the end of URL.

Comment: I tried your example by using `Yii::app->UrlManager->createUrl(['route', 'parameters'])`. But still special characters are encoded. So finally, I settled for hardcoding url,. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you did something wrong. I gave you example ready to cope&paste - did you tried use it without changing anything?

Comment: Yes. Without changing anything it is working. That's hardcoded 100. But the moment I want to include `$(this).val()` to it, it does html encoding.

Comment: In my example there is not hardcoded anything, value for param is appended in JS.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I will modify the code as you have suggested. I guess the mistake I was doing is using `.` operator for concatenation while it is `+` operator in JavaScript.